# AVAssetImageGenerator - Generate thumbnail at 5 seconds

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avasset, avassetimagegenerator

Seems simple enough. I just want the thumbnail from 5 seconds into the video:

```
AVURLAsset *asset1 = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] options:nil];
AVAssetImageGenerator *generate1 = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:asset1];
generate1.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = YES;
NSError *err = NULL;
Float64 seconds = 5;
int32_t preferredTimeScale = 30;
CMTime actualTime;
CMTime inTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(seconds, preferredTimeScale);
CMTimeShow(inTime);
CGImageRef oneRef = [generate1 copyCGImageAtTime:inTime actualTime:&actualTime error:&err];
```

The output is this:

```
Printing description of actualTime:
(CMTime) actualTime = 83 1000ths of a second {
  value = 83
  timescale = 1000
  flags = kCMTimeFlags_Valid
  epoch = 0
}
Printing description of inTime:
(CMTime) inTime = 150 30ths of a second {
  value = 150
  timescale = 30
  flags = kCMTimeFlags_Valid
  epoch = 0
}
```

Why is the `actualTime` different than the `inTime`??? How can I get the image at 5 seconds into the video?

Comment: Are you sure the video is not too short?

Comment: Yes, the video is 3 minutes long.

Comment: Could you please add to the post `asset1.duration` value?

Comment: CMTimeGetSeconds(asset1.duration) logs this: `duration: 180.203000`

Comment: So is the image actually wrong? Your video _could_ have an extremely low frame rate.

Comment: Well, it grabs the frame at 83 1000ths of a second, which is the first frame. This frame is black so it useless to me. I need a frame that is roughly 5 seconds into the video.

Comment: Is it a local video or remote video? Maybe you try to thumbnail something which was not loaded yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [requestedTimeToleranceBefore](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avassetimagegenerator/1390571-requestedtimetolerancebefore) and [requestedTimeToleranceAfter](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avassetimagegenerator/1387751-requestedtimetoleranceafter):

```
generate1.requestedTimeToleranceBefore = kCMTimeZero
generate1.requestedTimeToleranceAfter = kCMTimeZero
```

> **var requestedTimeToleranceBefore: CMTime**
>
> The maximum length of time before a requested time for which an image
>   may be generated.
>
> **var requestedTimeToleranceAfter: CMTime**
>
> The maximum length of time after a requested time for which an image
>   may be generated.

Comment: This doesn't help: `Printing description of actualTime:
(CMTime) actualTime = {
  value = 6143422688
  timescale = 0
  flags = 0
  epoch = 4320052688
}`